# Approach to maximizing $A^Ty = c$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces, numerical-linear-algebra

I am currently trying to estimate the value of $\lVert A^{-1}\rVert_1$ by choosing a vector $y$ such that the ratio $\lVert z\rVert/\lVert y\rVert$ is large and z is the solution to $Az=y$. I am choosing y as the solution to $A^Ty = c$ where c is a vector of $\pm 1$s with the signs being chosen so that ($A=LU$) $v$ is maximized in $U^Tv = c$ and $A^Ty = c$ can be solved with $L^Ty = v$. I am having some trouble determining what sign to assign c in order to maximize v.

Comment: Out of interest, could you explain why you are doing this procedure to estimate what you want?

Comment: In scenarios where computing $A^{-1}$ is too costly or impossible

Comment: Oh, no, I mean I have never seen this procedure before and I don't immediately see how you would be able to estimate $A^{-1}$ using this. Is there a name for it so I could look it up?

Comment: I am trying to estimate $\lVert A^{-1}\rVert_1$ not $A^{-1}$. I am not sure if this method has a name but I believe it is similar to inverse iteration.

Comment: Ah, OK. I guess I don't understand the method, so I will be following this post. :)